# Square loop above a wire with a current running through the wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits

A rectangular loop is above a wire with a current running through it. If the loop is connected to an external circuit, what is the EMF generated by the loop to the circuit? There's a bit more to it than the question posed, but the premise is the same. I need to start with $F = qv \times B$ ($v$ is the wire itself moving) and B is the magnetic field. The loop is held a distance b above the wire and has height a. Is the B in question the total magnetic field from b $\to$ a? i.e. should I integrate the magnetic field FIRST so as to not have any dependency on the radial component in my final solution? Or is there another way to handle this?

[image: Loop above wire]

Comment: A diagram is in order.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \quad\text {The flux rule gaves us EMF and it is: }
\varepsilon=-\frac{d}{d t} \Phi \text { and flux is }\Phi=BA \\ \text { (the wire's position stays perpendicular to the B-field so BA is valid as flux for this case }\\
\text { where A=aL,area of the loop) and Ampere's Law shows: } \\
B=\frac{\mu_{0} I}{2 \pi s} \text { so: }\Phi=\frac{\mu_{0}I A}{2 \pi}  \frac{1}{s}\text {. Rest is just taking the derivative. } \text {For your question about the}\\
\text {order of integration, it is far more easy to use Ampere's Law but if you don't want to use}\\
\text{I recommend use the symmetry for the straight wire.}
\end{array} 
$$

Comment: Since B is a function of the distance, r, from the wire, you will need to integrate BL dr to get an effective value for, s.

Comment: Great thanks! I had forgotten about that rule there and was trying to use something else. This makes a lot more sense with the other parts of the problem!